# Webbrowser Threading in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, browser

I am trying to limit the time to open webbrowser in vb.net; The conclusion after lots of search seems the threading! I tried the code below; that includes 2 methods I've tried, but nothing working;
I am trying to open the website in 10 seconds in another thread, if website did not respond, then go to the next website and discard that one; my codes are below:
FIRST TRIAL:

```
Option Explicit On
  Option Strict On
  Imports System.Threading

 Public Class Form1
Dim WorkerThread As Thread
Dim StopThread As Boolean = True

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(" ************************** This is the MAIN thread ************************** ")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show(" ************************** This is the SECOND thread ************************** ")
    If StopThread = False Then
        StopThread = True
    Else
        StopThread = False
        WorkerThread = New Thread(AddressOf Navigate)
        WorkerThread.IsBackground = True
        WorkerThread.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Navigate()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mekdam.com")
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub

End Class
```

SECOND TRIAL

```
    Option Explicit On
    Option Strict On
    Imports System.Threading

  Public Class Form1
Dim WorkerThread As Thread
Dim StopThread As Boolean = True

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(" ************************** This is the MAIN thread ************************** ")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show(" ************************** This is the SECOND thread ************************** ")
    If StopThread = False Then
        StopThread = True
    Else
        StopThread = False
        WorkerThread = New Thread(AddressOf Navigate)
        WorkerThread.IsBackground = True
        WorkerThread.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Navigate()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mekdam.com")
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: what do you means that fails ????System.exception ????At memory webbrowser cannot be used in separate thread.to do this you need to use another type of control if i'm not wrong.Howevere somewhere in my computer i should have something that i'have done for a friend which open several browser in mta apartment but not with original browser.....

Comment: Hi makemoney; thank you for answering; I hope you make more money :-) I appreciate it if you find that code; what I am facing with is that when I open many site, when one of them doesn't open for long time the program will be delayed; I want to discard websites that take more than 2 seconds to load; then load the next one; is there another method other than threading??

Comment: im'm searching i will update you later i'm little bit sure that was something related to com ....not sure .....

Comment: OK makemoney; I appreciate that ;-)